# Ordem aleatória com paginação MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Olá,
Estou precisando ordenar aleatoriamente resultado da minha consulta e exibir paginação usando mysql. A ordenação e paginação estão funcionando perfeitamente.

Sempre quando é feito a paginação, por conta da utilização do `ORDER BY RAND();` os resultados são aleatórios e repetidos na paginação.

Gostaria de saber como utilizar o `ORDER BY RAND();` para que os registros sempre sejam apresentados aleatórios em cada consulta (não necessariamente em cada pagina) sem repetir nas páginas seguintes.

```
SELECT * FROM tabela1 WHERE Id= $id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $inicial,$final
```

Comment: @Everson coloquei, mas é indiferente o exemplo pois é a forma de utilizar o resultado randomico com paginação que á a questão. Os registros não podem ser repetidos nas paginas subsequentes. O aleatório  tem que ser feito uma unica vez no resultado da consulta sem paginação.

Comment: a exibição é feita normalmente com php, calculando a paginação corretamente com o numero inicial de registros, tudo certo.

Answer (score 2):

O que você pode fazer é:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM tabela1 LIMIT $inicial, $final
) as t
ORDER BY RAND();
```

Desta forma, os registros referentes à paginação são selecionados pelo `SELECT` interno e posteriormente são ordenados de forma aleatória. Sem fazer isso, o `RAND` é executado antes do `LIMIT`, então a cada página corre o risco de registros ficarem duplicados (entenda duplicado como já exibido em outra página), pois como a ordem será aleatória, não tem como garantir quais serão os registros entre `$inicial` e `$final`.

> Veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a48a7/1).

Comment: Bem isso, perfeito! Porém, vamos supor se quiser fazer uma randomização geral e depois limitar, precisará armazenar todo os dados em cache randomizados e depois realizar a limitação por JS, pois na segunda execução do mesmo SQL o resultado não será o mesmo.